# css absolute position an inner div to the top of the page ignoring parents relative position

Tags: css

is there a way to absolute position an inner div to the top of the page ignoring parents relative position?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, unless you re-locate it in the DOM.

(*using `position:fixed` might be an alternative if you want it to be window related instead of document related*)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute;` and negative values:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
      <div id="child">
           The child's content
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent
{
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

#child
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
}
```

This should do it. [Example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/eWj8Z/3/).

Comment: Updated to include position relative.

Comment: is there a way to completely ignore the parent?

Comment: Only by taking the child out of the parent in the document. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/eWj8Z/4/